# Testing c# in Rider with xUnit

Tags: c#, .net, xunit, rider

it's my first question here, I'll try to be as brief as possible.

I started learning c#, but because I've been programming in java for 3 months and wanted to try something new but similar, since I loved using intelij I downloaded Rider(student license). I'm learning using pluralsight tutorial where unit tests are mentioned. I've decided to learn them. I created 2 projects, first - printing hello world on the console, and 
second - performing a simple test. I've added reference and I pressed run tests, but only question marks showed up. Then I pressed run previous tests, nothing happened and green "run" arrows became crossed. I'm really frustrated. Can someone help me, thanks in advance. I really want to stick with Rider IDE
Rider version 2019.3.4
xunit 2.4.11
.net core 3.1
[little screen here of what's going on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ETE1O.png)

Comment: Is there a tooltip on the crossed green "run" arrow (it should explain why you can't run tests)? Could you try to click on it (in case of some configuration problem, Rider can suggest actions that fix the problem). Could you also share the content of the `One.Tests.csproj` file?

Comment: Sory for late response I am using dotnet test in terminal  and it works ok.. but I'd still love to fix testing with ui. I've recreated the project.After i clicked crossed green arrow and it says Unfortunately, it's impossible to discover unit tests in some of your projects. :(
Below you can find the error details for each project.

Project: TestProject1 (C:\Users\user\RiderProjects\ConsoleApp1\TestProject1\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\TestProject1.dll)
  No tests discovered

Comment: content of testproject1.csproj :
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>

        <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="16.5.0"/>
        <PackageReference Include="xunit" Version="2.4.0"/>
        <PackageReference Include="xunit.runner.visualstudio" Version="2.4.1"/>
        <PackageReference Include="coverlet.collector" Version="1.2.0"/>
    </ItemGroup>

</Project>

Comment: Strange, it should work. Could you please share logs (click on the top-level Help menu and choose "Compress Logs and Show in Explorer")?